# How to simulate a django form submission with a button click on a different page?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am running in a situation where I want to simulate a form behaviour when a button is clicked on a different page.

For example by default a url '/add_user/' has a form where a user provides his name, email address, etc. When he clicks submit button on this form it creates an entry in database using django's form.save() method. Which essentially is depended on modelform functionality.

Now I have added a new url called '/subscribe/' where one can subscribe to a newsletter of his interest. I want to add all the name, email etc details from subscribe form and save it to database table which add_user link accesses.

I am aware that I can invoke a sql statement on a button click or using python library I can get the same result, however, I am wondering if there is any other way to simulate this because I want to keep my code decoupled from underlying database. In other words if in future if someone changes the database I don't want this code to fail.

Can you advise on how to do this?

Thanks.
Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a many to one relation between users and the subscribe database entry. Then when a user logs in and presses the subscribe button send that request to a view and process the entry.

You can find out which user is logged in with

```
user = request.user
```